# An element of the hamburger menu covers a child element

Tags: html, css

I have a hamburger menu that works quite well, except that when I click on the "Tienda" link, the second item does not show it entirety. It shows "marios" instead of "armarios", and I think it's because the "blog" element covers part of the "armarios" element. I don't know how to fix it. This is the css and html code.In this photo you can see what happens: https://postimg.cc/LnZfyJFT

```
            * {
            margin:0px;
            padding:0px;
        }
        
        #header {
            margin:auto;
            width:500px;
            font-family:'PT Sans Narrow', sans-serif;
        }
        
        ul, ol {
            list-style:none;
        }
        
        .nav > li {
            float:left;
        }
        
        .nav li a {
            background-color:#000;
            color:#fff;
            text-decoration:none;
            padding:10px 12px;
            display:block;
        }
        
        .nav li a:hover {
            background-color:#434343;
        }
        
        .nav li ul {
            display:none;
            position:absolute;
            min-width:140px;
        }
        
        .nav li:hover > ul {
            display:block;
        }
        
        .nav li ul li {
            position:relative;
        }
        
        .nav li ul li ul {
            right:-140px;
            top:0px;
        }
        .icono
        {
            width:40px;/*tama�o del icono*/
            height:30px;
        }

<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="estilos_menu.css?<?php echo date('l jS \of F Y h:i:s A'); ?>">   
    </head>
    <body>

<div id="header">
                        <ul class="nav">
                                <li><img class="icono"  src="hamburguer.png">
                                        <ul>
                                                <li><a href="">Tienda</a>
                                                        <ul>
                                                            <li><a href="">Ver todo</a></li>
                                                                <li><a href="">Armarios</a></li>
                                                                <li><a href="">Sillas</a></li>
                                                                <li><a href="">Sillones</a></li>
                                                                <li><a href="">Sofás</a></li>
                                                                <li><a href="">Mesas</a></li>
                                                                <li><a href="">Mesillas y cajoneras</a></li>
                                                                <li><a href="">Lámparas</a></li>
                                                        </ul>
                                                </li>
                                                <li><a href="blog_principal.php">Blog</a>
                                        <ul>
                                                <li><a href="minimalista.php">Estilo minimalista</a></li>
                                                <li><a href="nordico.php">Estilo nórdico</a></li>
                                                <li><a href="retro.php">Estilo retro</a></li>
                                                <li><a href="rustico.php">Estilo rústico</a></li>
                                                <li><a href="clasico.php">Estilo clásico</a></li>
                                                <li><a href="exteriores.php">Espacios exteriores</a></li>
                                                <li><a href="fusion_estilos.php">Fusión de estilos</a></li>                     
                                                </li>
                                        </ul>
                                </li>

                                </li>   
                        </ul>

                </div>              

    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple of options.

You can add a `z-index` in to make it stay on top of other elements. Specifically under `.nav li ul li ul {` like so:

```css
* {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

#header {
  margin: auto;
  width: 500px;
  font-family: 'PT Sans Narrow', sans-serif;
}

ul,
ol {
  list-style: none;
}

.nav>li {
  float: left;
}

.nav li a {
  background-color: #000;
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 10px 12px;
  display: block;
}

.nav li a:hover {
  background-color: #434343;
}

.nav li ul {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  min-width: 140px;
}

.nav li:hover>ul {
  display: block;
}

.nav li ul li {
  position: relative;
}

.nav li ul li ul {
  right: -140px;
  top: 0px;
  z-index: 1;
}

.icono {
  width: 40px;
  /*tama�o del icono*/
  height: 30px;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="estilos_menu.css?<?php echo date('l jS \of F Y h:i:s A'); ?>">
</head>

<body>

  <div id="header">
    <ul class="nav">
      <li><img class="icono" src="hamburguer.png">
        <ul>
          <li><a href="">Tienda</a>
            <ul>
              <li><a href="">Ver todo</a></li>
              <li><a href="">Armarios</a></li>
              <li><a href="">Sillas</a></li>
              <li><a href="">Sillones</a></li>
              <li><a href="">Sofás</a></li>
              <li><a href="">Mesas</a></li>
              <li><a href="">Mesillas y cajoneras</a></li>
              <li><a href="">Lámparas</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li><a href="blog_principal.php">Blog</a>
            <ul>
              <li><a href="minimalista.php">Estilo minimalista</a></li>
              <li><a href="nordico.php">Estilo nórdico</a></li>
              <li><a href="retro.php">Estilo retro</a></li>
              <li><a href="rustico.php">Estilo rústico</a></li>
              <li><a href="clasico.php">Estilo clásico</a></li>
              <li><a href="exteriores.php">Espacios exteriores</a></li>
              <li><a href="fusion_estilos.php">Fusión de estilos</a></li>
          </li>
          </ul>
      </li>

      </li>
      </ul>

  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Alternatively you can move the menu over so it doesn't overlap in the first place. You would change that by removing `right: -140px;` and adding `left: 140px;` under `.nav li ul li ul {`.

```css
* {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

#header {
  margin: auto;
  width: 500px;
  font-family: 'PT Sans Narrow', sans-serif;
}

ul,
ol {
  list-style: none;
}

.nav>li {
  float: left;
}

.nav li a {
  background-color: #000;
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 10px 12px;
  display: block;
}

.nav li a:hover {
  background-color: #434343;
}

.nav li ul {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  min-width: 140px;
}

.nav li:hover>ul {
  display: block;
}

.nav li ul li {
  position: relative;
}

.nav li ul li ul {
  left: 140px;
  top: 0px;
}

.icono {
  width: 40px;
  /*tama�o del icono*/
  height: 30px;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="estilos_menu.css?<?php echo date('l jS \of F Y h:i:s A'); ?>">
</head>

<body>

  <div id="header">
    <ul class="nav">
      <li><img class="icono" src="hamburguer.png">
        <ul>
          <li><a href="">Tienda</a>
            <ul>
              <li><a href="">Ver todo</a></li>
              <li><a href="">Armarios</a></li>
              <li><a href="">Sillas</a></li>
              <li><a href="">Sillones</a></li>
              <li><a href="">Sofás</a></li>
              <li><a href="">Mesas</a></li>
              <li><a href="">Mesillas y cajoneras</a></li>
              <li><a href="">Lámparas</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li><a href="blog_principal.php">Blog</a>
            <ul>
              <li><a href="minimalista.php">Estilo minimalista</a></li>
              <li><a href="nordico.php">Estilo nórdico</a></li>
              <li><a href="retro.php">Estilo retro</a></li>
              <li><a href="rustico.php">Estilo rústico</a></li>
              <li><a href="clasico.php">Estilo clásico</a></li>
              <li><a href="exteriores.php">Espacios exteriores</a></li>
              <li><a href="fusion_estilos.php">Fusión de estilos</a></li>
          </li>
          </ul>
      </li>

      </li>
      </ul>

  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Glad to hear it :)